# Gmaps4rails turbolink disable not working - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5, gmaps4rails

When I click on my contact button in my navbar the map at the bottom of the page is not loading unless I refresh. When I click on the contact button this is what I get:

[image: error]

Notice the console errors it is giving me. I have tried both of these lines within the same link_to tag `'data-no-turbolink' => true` and  `:data => {no_turbolink:'true'}`

The only way it works is when I refresh which gives me the correct look:

[image: correct way it is supposed to look]

This is what my navbar code is for the contact portion `<%= link_to 'Contact Us', '/contacts', class: "dropdown-toggle", data_toggle: "dropdown",  :data => {no_turbolink:'true'} %>`

Here is the code for my map in my contact form:

```
<script>
    handler2 = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler2.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'contact_map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler2.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 34.047103,
      "lng": -118.434072
    }
  ]);
  handler2.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler2.fitMapToBounds();

});

    </script>
```

I have tried the different suggestions in similar questions asked but nothing is working for me. My goal is to have the map always load whenever I click on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may cek this link for reference [disable turbolink on specific link](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links) , for your code above you can try this code below

```
<div data-turbolinks="false">
  <%= link_to 'Contact Us', '/contacts', class: "dropdown-toggle", data_toggle: "dropdown" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm the only difference was my links were in a list so instead of putting the turbolinks part in a <div> I put it in my <li>